# Highlight country once selected with dropdown D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map of Africa which I loaded using D3 which features several columns including a column named ADMIN which features each country's name. I'm trying to highlight the country on my map that is selected in my dropdown. For example if I select Algeria in my drop down, Algeria will highlight on my map. The map itself loads fine as well as the dropdown. I'm just having trouble coordinating the interaction between the dropdown function and the highlight function so that the selected country actually highlights.

```js
//begin script when window loads
window.onload = setMap();

var attrArray = ["Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cameroon", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Congo", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Djibouti", "DR Congo", "Egypt", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Eswatini",
  "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome & Principe", "Senegal",
  "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
];

var expressed = attrArray[0];

//set up choropleth map
function setMap() {
  //map frame dimensions
  var width = 1200,
    height = 1000;

  //create new svg container for the map
  var map = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "map")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  //create Albers equal area conic projection centered on France
  var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
    .scale(600)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2.7])
    .clipAngle(85)
    .precision(.1);

  var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)

  var graticule = d3.geoGraticule()
    .step([5, 5]); //place graticule lines every 5 degrees of longitude and latitude

  //create graticule background
  var gratBackground = map.append("path")
    .datum(graticule.outline()) //bind graticule background
    .attr("class", "gratBackground") //assign class for styling
    .attr("d", path) //project graticule

  //Example 2.6 line 5...create graticule lines
  var gratLines = map.selectAll(".gratLines")
    .data(graticule.lines()) //bind graticule lines to each element to be created
    .enter() //create an element for each datum
    .append("path") //append each element to the svg as a path element
    .attr("class", "gratLines") //assign class for styling
    .attr("d", path); //project graticule lines

  //use queue to parallelize asynchronous data loading
  d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/AfricaCountries.csv") //load attributes from csv
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/world.topojson") //load background spatial data
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/Africa.TOPOJSON")
    .await(callback);

  function callback(error, csvData, world, africa) {
    //translate europe TopoJSON
    var basemapCountries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries),
      choroplethCountries = topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries).features;

    //select graticule elements that will be created
    //add Europe countries to map
    var countries = map.append("path")
      .datum(basemapCountries)
      .attr("class", "countries")
      .attr("d", path);

    //add France regions to map
    var regions = map.selectAll(".regions")
      .data(choroplethCountries)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "regions " + d.properties.ADMIN;
      })
      .attr("d", path)

    console.log(countries);
    console.log(regions)

    createDropdown(csvData);
  };

  function createDropdown(csvData) {
    //add select element
    var dropdown = d3.select("body")
      .append("select")
      .attr("class", "dropdown")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("change", function() {
        highlight(d.properties);
      });

    //add initial option
    var titleOption = dropdown.append("option")
      .attr("class", "titleOption")
      .attr("disabled", "true")
      .text("Select Country");

    //add attribute name options
    var attrOptions = dropdown.selectAll("attrOptions")
      .data(attrArray)
      .enter()
      .append("option")
      .attr("value", function(d) {
        return d
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d
      });
  };

  //function to highlight enumeration units and bars
  function highlight(props) {
    //change stroke
    var selected = d3.selectAll("." + props.ADMIN)
      .style("stroke", "blue")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
    console.log(props.ADMIN);
  };
};
```

```css
.countries {
  fill: #0B1E38;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.regions {
  fill: #316331;
}

.gratLines {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.gratBackground {
  fill: #0B1E38;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #999;
}

option {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Need to do some debugging, try console.log the props.ADMIN value, what's that highlight function doing and if it's even being called etc. Sorry don't have enough time to look into it now.

Comment: I'm pretty new at javascript and d3 etc but I have the highlight function being called in the createdropdown function which is in itself called in callback function. I've slightly changed the code and updated it in Github but I do realize props.ADMIN isn't logging at all so I assume there's a problem there. I also assume in general however that maybe I'm not calling the highlight function correctly. I attempted to modify an example I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225000/5015356), you need to get the value of the selected option using the attribute `value` on the `select` element - which is available as `this` in this function.

```js
var attrArray = ["Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cameroon", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Congo", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Djibouti", "DR Congo", "Egypt", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Eswatini",
  "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome & Principe", "Senegal",
  "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
];

//map frame dimensions
var width = 1200,
  height = 1000;

//create new svg container for the map
var map = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "map")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//create Albers equal area conic projection centered on France
var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .scale(600)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2.7])
  .clipAngle(85)
  .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection)

var graticule = d3.geoGraticule()
  .step([5, 5]); //place graticule lines every 5 degrees of longitude and latitude

//create graticule background
var gratBackground = map.append("path")
  .datum(graticule.outline()) //bind graticule background
  .attr("class", "gratBackground") //assign class for styling
  .attr("d", path) //project graticule

//Example 2.6 line 5...create graticule lines
var gratLines = map.selectAll(".gratLines")
  .data(graticule.lines()) //bind graticule lines to each element to be created
  .enter() //create an element for each datum
  .append("path") //append each element to the svg as a path element
  .attr("class", "gratLines") //assign class for styling
  .attr("d", path); //project graticule lines

//use queue to parallelize asynchronous data loading
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/world.topojson") //load background spatial data
  .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/Africa.TOPOJSON")
  .await(callback);

function callback(error, world, africa) {
  //translate europe TopoJSON
  var basemapCountries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries),
    choroplethCountries = topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries).features;

  //select graticule elements that will be created
  //add Europe countries to map
  var countries = map.append("path")
    .datum(basemapCountries)
    .attr("class", "countries")
    .attr("d", path);

  //add France regions to map
  var regions = map.selectAll(".regions")
    .data(choroplethCountries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "regions " + d.properties.ADMIN;
    })
    .attr("d", path);

  createDropdown();
};

function createDropdown() {
  //add select element
  var dropdown = d3.select("body")
    .append("select")
    .attr("class", "dropdown")
    .on("change", function() {
      // The value is the name of the country
      var countryName = this.value;
      highlight(countryName);
    });

  //add initial option
  var titleOption = dropdown.append("option")
    .attr("class", "titleOption")
    .attr("disabled", "true")
    .text("Select Country");

  //add attribute name options
  var attrOptions = dropdown.selectAll("attrOptions")
    .data(attrArray)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
};

//function to highlight enumeration units and bars
function highlight(countryName) {
  //change stroke
  var selected = d3.selectAll("." + countryName)
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .style("stroke-width", "2")
  console.log(countryName);
};
```

```css
.countries {
  fill: #0B1E38;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.regions {
  fill: #316331;
}

.gratLines {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.gratBackground {
  fill: #0B1E38;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #999;
}

option {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `class` is not the right place to store country names, even though it is an easy selector. Country names of multiple words are not registered correctly, like the selector for "Sierra Leone" is `".Sierra.Leone"` and not `".Sierra Leone"`. Besides, try selecting "Congo"; every country that has the word "Congo" in it gets highlighted. You'd make your life much easier by creating a custom attribute "data-country" and selecting the correct country using `d3.select("[data-country='" + countryName + "']")`. See also [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) on attribute selectors.

In addition, the names in `attrArray` and the names in the countries map did not line up, so some highlighting did not work at all. I recommend just taking the names from the TopoJSON or creating a mapping from CSV name to TopoJSON name.

```js
//map frame dimensions
var width = 1200,
  height = 1000;

//create new svg container for the map
var map = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "map")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//create Albers equal area conic projection centered on France
var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .scale(600)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2.7])
  .clipAngle(85)
  .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection)

var graticule = d3.geoGraticule()
  .step([5, 5]); //place graticule lines every 5 degrees of longitude and latitude

//create graticule background
var gratBackground = map.append("path")
  .datum(graticule.outline()) //bind graticule background
  .attr("class", "gratBackground") //assign class for styling
  .attr("d", path) //project graticule

//Example 2.6 line 5...create graticule lines
var gratLines = map.selectAll(".gratLines")
  .data(graticule.lines()) //bind graticule lines to each element to be created
  .enter() //create an element for each datum
  .append("path") //append each element to the svg as a path element
  .attr("class", "gratLines") //assign class for styling
  .attr("d", path); //project graticule lines

//use queue to parallelize asynchronous data loading
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/world.topojson") //load background spatial data
  .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sharitau/website/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal/data/Africa.TOPOJSON")
  .await(callback);

function callback(error, world, africa) {
  //translate europe TopoJSON
  var basemapCountries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries),
    choroplethCountries = topojson.feature(africa, africa.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries).features;

  //select graticule elements that will be created
  //add Europe countries to map
  var countries = map.append("path")
    .datum(basemapCountries)
    .attr("class", "countries")
    .attr("d", path);

  //add France regions to map
  var regions = map.selectAll(".regions")
    .data(choroplethCountries)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "regions")
    .attr("data-country", function(d) {
      return d.properties.ADMIN;
    })
    .attr("d", path);

  var countryNames = choroplethCountries.map(function(d) {
    return d.properties.ADMIN;
  }).sort();
  createDropdown(countryNames);
};

function createDropdown(countryNames) {
  //add select element
  var dropdown = d3.select("body")
    .append("select")
    .attr("class", "dropdown")
    .on("change", function() {
      // The value is the name of the country
      var countryName = this.value;
      highlight(countryName);
    });

  //add initial option
  var titleOption = dropdown.append("option")
    .attr("class", "titleOption")
    .attr("disabled", "true")
    .text("Select Country");

  //add attribute name options
  var attrOptions = dropdown.selectAll("attrOptions")
    .data(countryNames)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
};

//function to highlight enumeration units and bars
function highlight(countryName) {
  //change stroke
  var selected = d3.selectAll("[data-country='" + countryName + "']")
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .style("stroke-width", "2")
  console.log(countryName);
};
```

```css
.countries {
  fill: #0B1E38;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.regions {
  fill: #316331;
}

.gratLines {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.gratBackground {
  fill: #0B1E38;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #999;
}

option {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, there were some unnecessary complications in your code.

- There was no need to use the `c3` library;
- You gave the `select` element `.attr('d', path)`, which doesn't do anything. It only works for the `path` element in the SVG ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really thought I had caught where my csv and my original shapefile differed in country name but you're right, I could have gotten the country name from the shapefile as those were the exact names that would be needed to be matched. I'll go back and edit that and I know I don't need C3 yet. There was something else I was considering doing with it later but I've not gotten there yet as I wanted to make sure the core of the program worked first.

Answer (score 0):

It look to me more a JS related issue than a d3 related issue:

Here you have a d variable that appear seemingly out of nowhere

```
function createDropdown(csvData) {
    //add select element
    var dropdown = d3.select("body")
      .append("select")
      .attr("class", "dropdown")
      .attr("d", path) // I don't think a select can use this
      .on("change", function() {
        highlight(d.properties); // where does this d come from a actually ? It is not provided by the function itself so what it is ?
      });
  // rest of code
}
```

And here :

```
    function highlight(props) {
        //change stroke
        var selected = d3.selectAll("." + props.ADMIN) // <= here
          .style("stroke", "blue")
          .style("stroke-width", "2")
        console.log(props.ADMIN);
      };
```

you select all elements with the class that match props.ADMIN but your code never actually use this class on any elements. The paths created from choroplethCountries data use the "regions " + d.properties.ADMIN class, so if you want to highlight those, you should use the ".regions " + d.properties.ADMIN selector.

Did you tried to run your code in debug mode to check how it behave exactly?
Also, given the fact that your a beginner in JS, I would advise you to consider the possibility of not using d3. This is a very general purpose library, which give it a great flexibility but it also mean that you have to learn a lot of things before using it efficiently.
If you are free to choose the tech, maybe it would be worthwhile to invest a bit of your time in investigating alternatives solution more specialized in the type of visualization you are going for.

Comment: I appreciate you for your help and advice. I considered using leaflet which I find a bit easier, I don't have much experience in either honestly, but ultimately chose d3 since I recently did another assignment in it and though to use some of that assignment as a base for this assignment. I should have put more thought into it though.

Comment: Hello can you help me again. I'm now trying to unhighlight when a new entry is selected and i think i'm quite close as i've followed a few examples online, but there's a disconnect happening between my code that logs all of the unselected elements and the spatial data which should be unhighighted. I feel like .filter() should help if I rerun the regions portion but dont quite understand how to arrange that puzzle yet. Obviously you don't have to and I know I'm asking for a bit much, even if you could point me in the direction of an example I could look at, that would help

Comment: @Sharitau Given the usage of log you mad in the code you provided and the fact you also mention it there, I'll ask again : do you know how to use a debugger ? I don't want to sound unrespectfull but large amount of novice dev don't know what it is or how to use it. The problem you describe me typically sound like something you can efficiently resolve by running your code in debug mode.

Comment: Honestly, no. What I've been doing is amending my code, running it in my server and checking for errors in the developer console

Comment: However, I did JUST get the dehighlight to work which...has taken me over 24 hours but it's super gratifying